# Cocos2d update function equivalent?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, function

I'm looking for an equivalent of the cocos2d update:(ccTime)delta function for use without cocos2d. I need to perform a check as many times a second as possible. Are there any native functions like this or drawRect that are called as frequently as possible that I could use?

Pseudo code:

```
timeElapsed += delta;
if (timeElapsed > beatTime)
{
    timeElapsed = 0;
    beat++;
    for (SoundBlock* block in blocks)
    {
        [block play];
    }
}
```

Essentially, I would like to perform a check like this as many times as possible per second.

Comment: Can you give a (pseudo-code) example of what you want to do?

Comment: Just added the pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to check something as fast as possible, since that would lead to performance issues.

If you want something that updates with the display, you could use [CADisplayLink](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html). You can google around for examples, like this [one](http://zearfoss.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/drawing-with-cadisplaylink/).

If you don't need to link it to display refresh, you can set up an [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html), or use a variant of [performSelector:withObject:afterDelay](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3ainModes%3a).

If you need high resolution timers, look at [this technical note](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2169/_index.html).

NSTimer and performSelector both have a resolution around 50-100 ms, which is not sufficient for sound playback.

I would recommend you use a separate real time thread with mach_wait_until() as explained in the tech note. Using the code from **Listing 2** in the technote, something playing a sound every `BEATS_PER_SEC` using `play_beat()`, would look like this:

```
void play_beat_thread(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    mach_timebase_info(&timebase_info);
    uint64_t time_to_wait = nanos_to_abs(10ULL * BEATS_PER_SEC);
    uint64_t next = mach_absolute_time();
    while (true)
    {
        next = next + time_to_wait;
        mach_wait_until(next);
        play_beat();
    }
}
```

If you want more advice on high resolution audio timing, I suggest you reframe this question along the lines *"How do I manually schedule high resolution audio playback on iOS/OS X"*.

Comment: Hmm. The app I'm working on is a beat sequencer so I'm trying to check for beats to play based on elapsed time. I might be able to essentially have the check recursively call itself every x amount of time so I literally only am checking every time I need to check. That would be very efficient!

Comment: @LoganShire if 60 checks / s is enough, CADisplayLink might be sufficient. NSTimer usually doesn't provide high resolution timing. You should also consider what thread you're using to do this. You can't do a busy-loop on the main thread without locking the entire UI. I added a link to a technical note regarding high resolution timers. It has some examples that should get you started if you need to check very often. Be wary of threading issues though.

Comment: I'm gonna try the recursive perform selector solution and see if that works as it would be by far the most efficient solution, as it only would call every time I need to update. If that doesn't work I'll try the display link.

Comment: @LoganShire The problem with perform selector is that is similar to NSTimer when it comes to precision.